# Bypass WAF/IDS with SQLMAP?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap, waf

How can I use SQLMAP to run tests on a website with a WAF/IDS? Suppose I want to run something like this:

```
python sqlmap.py -u http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/standard.html&id=30 --dbs
```

How can I test against WAF/IDs in this case?

Comment: There is a lot of documentation for sqlmap. Start [here](http://sqlmap.org/) and come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should use the option *-tamper* and use the [tamper scripts](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/tree/master/tamper). However, please consult the command line helper, or visit the SQLmap [wiki page](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage).